# Why in this architecture 'Map' function can't infer the map datatype?

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance

'Usuario' it's a simple class with some properties.
Map is a generic function what I want to use in other child clases like 'Usuario':

```
   public abstract class Repository : IRepository
    {
        public TEntity Map<TEntity>() where TEntity : Repository, new()
        {
            TEntity clone = new TEntity();
            PropertyInfo[] objProperties = this.GetType().GetProperties();

            foreach (PropertyInfo pi in objProperties)
            {
                if (pi.PropertyType.IsPrimitive ||
                            pi.PropertyType.FullName.Contains("System.Int") || //when int primitives are nullables it's needed
                            pi.PropertyType.FullName.Contains("System.DateTime") ||
                            pi.PropertyType.FullName.Contains("System.Decimal") ||
                            pi.PropertyType.FullName.Contains("System.Float") ||
                            pi.PropertyType.FullName.Contains("System.Double") ||
                            pi.PropertyType.FullName.Contains("System.String") ||
                            pi.PropertyType.FullName.Contains("System.Boolean") ||
                            pi.PropertyType.FullName.Contains("System.Byte") ||
                            pi.PropertyType.FullName.Contains("System.Guid"))
                {
                    if (pi.CanWrite)
                    {
                        pi.SetValue(clone, pi.GetValue(this));
                    }
                }
            }

            return clone;
        }

    }
```

Here is the usage:

```
// GET: api/Usuarios/5
        [ResponseType(typeof(Usuario))]
        public IHttpActionResult GetUsuario(int id)
        {
            Usuario usuario = db.Usuarios.Find(id);
            if (usuario == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return Ok(usuario.Map<Usuario>());
        }
```

Why I need to put `usuario.Map<Usuario>();` instead of `usuario.Map();` if usuario var is of Usuario datatype? It can't be infered?

Comment: No. Just how would you *expect* the type parameter to be inferred? How is the compiler supposed to know you intend any specific type? Just because `usuario` is of type `Usuario`, doesn't mean that the only logical type parameter is `Usuario`. You could just as well use *any* other type that derives from `Repository` and has a parameterless constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't infer types by return types, however a slight change in architecture lets you not need to do it, you need to make the base class generic.

```
public abstract class Repository<TEntity> : IRepository 
    where TEntity : Repository<TEntity>, new()
{
    public TEntity Map()
    {
        TEntity clone = new TEntity();
        // (Snip)
        return clone;
    }
}
```

Then in `Usuario` you would change it from

```
public class Usuario : Repository
```

to

```
public class Usuario : Repository<Usuario>
```

and your useage becomes

```
[ResponseType(typeof(Usuario))]
public IHttpActionResult GetUsuario(int id)
{
    Usuario usuario = db.Usuarios.Find(id);
    if (usuario == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    return Ok(usuario.Map());
}
```

This is called the [curiously recurring template pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern).